# Looping a list element against dictonary values

Tags: python, dictionary, arraylist

i am having an list of numbers in the form of list and i want to compare the list element against the dictionary values

i tried the solution in 2 ways .

```
lr =[47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
di ={'Jhon':47, 'Emma':69, 'Kelly':76, 'Jason':97}

expected output : after removing unwanted elemnts from list[47, 69, 76, 97]

method 1: ( Success)
lr =[47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
di ={'Jhon':47, 'Emma':69, 'Kelly':76, 'Jason':97}
for i in lr:
    if i in di.values():
        ln.append(i)
print(ln)

===============success========================

**********************************************
Method 2: (Failed)

lr =[47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
di ={'Jhon':47, 'Emma':69, 'Kelly':76, 'Jason':97}
for i in lr:
    if i in di.values():
        pass
    else:
       lr.remove(i)
print(lr)

==================failed=======================

for method 2 i am getting result as [47, 69, 76, 88, 88, 97]
not sure what wrong in the method 2
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: You should not mutate a list while iterating over it. If you really need to do it, iterate over list(lr)

Comment: clearly state your question or goal...do what after comparing? if you already have a method that works then what is the question?

Comment: @ Eden,  when i am comparing and removing the element which is not present using the list.remove(), its not working .. so i want to know in the second method what was the error i am making ..
i am comparing  
lr =[47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
di ={'Jhon':47, 'Emma':69, 'Kelly':76, 'Jason':97}

Answer (score 0):

A little modification to your second method will give you the expected result.

```
lr =[47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
di ={'Jhon':47, 'Emma':69, 'Kelly':76, 'Jason':97}
for i in lr[:]: # note the slice notation for creating a copy of list
    if i in di.values():
        pass
    else:
       lr.remove(i)
print(lr)
```

The reason you were getting incorrect values was because you were modifying the list while iterating over it as pointed out by @Lior Cohen.

Here, I added additional print statements to show what exactly is happening with your list. Observe each iteration and you will see why mutating a list while iterating is a bad idea.

```
lr =[47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
di ={'Jhon':47, 'Emma':69, 'Kelly':76, 'Jason':97}
for index, i in enumerate(lr):
    print('Value:',i, 'Index:', index)
    if i in di.values():
        pass
    else:
        lr.remove(i)
    print('List:', lr)

# Output
Value: 47 Index: 0
List: [47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
Value: 64 Index: 1
List: [47, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
Value: 37 Index: 2
List: [47, 69, 76, 83, 95, 97]
Value: 83 Index: 3
List: [47, 69, 76, 95, 97]
Value: 97 Index: 4
List: [47, 69, 76, 95, 97]
```